# System freezes on wake from suspend only when Chrome is open

Tags: nvidia, suspend, chrome

I am using an operating system based on Ubuntu 20.04. If Chrome is open, the computer hangs while waking up from suspend and does not respond at all. If Chrome is not open, I can do suspend - wake up 20 times, no problem.

**My GPU Card**: GeForce GT 710

**Drivers and others**:

```
NVIDIA-SMI 470.86       Driver Version: 470.86       CUDA Version: 11.4
```

Although I checked all the logs, I could not find an error. Also, I purged all nvidia packages and installed them again.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: I think it has been answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/

Answer (score 1):

Chrome remembers your previous Chrome session if you logout or suspend when Chrome is open and if your operating system is configured to allow it. Chrome remembers all its open tabs and even remembers the exact time that a YouTube video was paused. If the only reason you suspend the computer is to save the state of the web browser and restore it later, then you don't need to suspend the operating system if you use Chrome. This feature requires a lot of memory. Chrome uses a lot of memory when it launches after your operating system wakes up from suspend. That's why Chrome does not respond at all. It doesn't respond because it doesn't have enough memory.

To free memory when your computer wakes up from suspend close Chrome before suspending Ubuntu. After Ubuntu is fully woken up from suspend it will free up the memory that it used to wake up, and you will be able to launch Chrome without it hanging or freezing.

Alternatively you can add more memory capacity to your computer. Before you add physical memory capacity to your computer you should check the size of the swap file. The default size of the swap file in Ubuntu 20.04 is 1.5GB, and the size of the swap file can be made larger.

As it turned it the problem was caused not by insufficient RAM, but by what seems to be a hardware fault in the GeForce GT 710 Nvidia graphics card, possibly memory related because a discrete graphics card has its own memory. Replacing the Nvidia graphics card with an ATI Radeon HD 5830 graphics card solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't think so it's a memory issue. The swap file is 8Gb and my system memory 32Gb DDR4-3200. Now I'm using ATI (ATI Radeon HD 5830) as a graphics card and I've tried Suspend/WakeUp about 20 times and I have not faced any issue.

And It's not a good idea to close chrome then open it again. I can also add chrome shutdown inside Suspend button. But it's not the right way for me.

Test Scenario: same chrome tabs open and softwares.